# TCP server client issue

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

First i am n00b in socket programming. So i decided to write simple data over lan tcp server 
My server code that handles incomming data is

```
    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{

    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    clientStream.ReadTimeout = 10;
    int size = 4096 * 1000;
    byte[] message = new byte[size];
    byte[] All = new byte[0];
    int bytesRead;
    string error = "";
    lock (this)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            All = new byte[0];
            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, size);
                    All = AddBArrays(All, message, bytesRead);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (All.Length > 0)
            {
                Message m = (Message)Tools.ByteArrayToObject(All);
                OnRecived(new RecivedArgs("localhost", (Message)Tools.ByteArrayToObject(All)));
            }
        }
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
byte[] AddBArrays(byte[] ar1, byte[] ar2, int read)
{
    byte[] concat = new byte[ar1.Length + read];
    if (ar1.Length != 0)
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(ar1, 0, concat, 0, ar1.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(ar2, 0, concat, ar1.Length, read);
    return concat;
}
```

it works but have some issues. It fales receiving files bigger then 100 mbs or smthng and also if i send data very often interval < 800 then data is lost. how should i improve my code? The large file issue is not so important the primary issue is the data loss in fast data sending.
tnx for help

Ok i now updated the code by the suggestions

```
private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{

    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    clientStream.ReadTimeout = 10;
    int size = 4096 * 1000;
    List<byte> Test = new List<byte>();
    byte[] message = new byte[size];
    byte[] All = new byte[0];
    int bytesRead;
    while (true)
    {
        //All = new byte[0];
        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;
            try
            {
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, size);
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                {
                    Test.Add(message[i]);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Test.Count > 0)
        {
            Message m = (Message)Tools.ByteArrayToObject(Test.ToArray());
            OnRecived(new RecivedArgs("localhost", m));
            Test = new List<byte>();
        }
    }
    tcpClient.Close();

}
```

but the issues still there

Edit--> large file issue fixed it was just a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' but it didn't throw a error.

Comment: Is the HandleClientComm method multithreaded...ie...are multiple threads coming in?

Comment: for each client one threat. but i have tested it only with one client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved the problem.
I simple send to much data to fast so data loss was unavoidable.

My optimized code is

```
private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    int size = 1;
    byte[] message = new byte[1];
    int bytesRead;
    while (true)
    {
        bytesRead = 0;
        if (clientStream.DataAvailable)
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 1);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            OnRecived(new RecivedArgs("tick", null));
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

i have tested intervals as low as 1 ms and no data loss :)
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

- The All byte array you should change to a `List<byte>`. You are creating instances like crazy right now.  The GC is probably working a lot more than it needs to. This might be slowing it down so much that it can't keep up.

Not really related to sockets:

- Make size a `const`
- NEVER lock `this`. Create a private field that you can lock.  In fact, I don't even think you need a lock here.
- remove the error string.

Comment: * Use AddRange() for adding to the List<byte>

Comment: also addrange copy's all message to List but most of times it is filled only by 250 bytes of data other is just zeros and i consider it a big waste of memory.